# Eclipse error installing jboss tools

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I've been trying to install jboss tools on Eclipse Mars but it fails everytime showin the following error :

> Unable to read repository at http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/mars/stable/updates/.
>   http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/mars/stable/updates/ is not a valid repository location.

I checked all the posts evoking this problem and all the solutions bellow did not work for me :

- Launching Eclipse from the command prompt and adding -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
- Checking the connection in the internal web browser (The connection works just fine )
- Deleting the oomph subfolders
- Deleting the cache folder of org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by configuring the JRE eclipse is pointing at :

1. Right click your project > properties
2. Select “Java Build Path” on left, then “JRE System Library”, click Edit…
3. Select "Workspace Default JRE"
4. Click "Installed JREs"
5. If you see JRE you want in the list select it (selecting a JDK is OK too)
6. If not, click Search…, navigate to Computer > Windows C: > Program Files > Java, then click OK
7. Now you should see all installed JREs, select the one you want
8. Click OK/Finish